# Keep Connection with Socket.io

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to connect at asterisk websocket, using [socket.io-client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client)

```
socket = io.connect(url ,{
    transports: ['websocket'],
    secure: true,
    'force new connection' : false,
    'reconnect' : true,
});
```

It works, but everytime I change or refresh page, websocket connection disconnect and reconnect (obviusly). My app is not "one-page-app".

There is a way for keep connection alive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There is a way for keep connection alive?

No.  Not if you allow the page to change in the browser.

When the browser changes pages, it will close all resources associated with the old page (including webSockets) and then it will initialize and open the new page.  You cannot change that.

The only way to keep a webSocket open is to put it in a window that does not change.  That would entail either converting to a single page app (that doesn't change pages) or putting the webSocket in a frame or window that doesn't change.  You could have the user install a browser extension (which can maintain persistent connections), but I assume that isn't what you're asking about.

Otherwise, you have to just manage things on your server to handle the fact that a page change within your site will close the old webSocket and open a new one.

Comment: @icy2k - Did this answer your question?  If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn your some reputation points for following the proper procedure here on stack overflow.